# Vue JS2 parent and child checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I have a list of lists:

```html
<ul>
      <li v-for="subregion in continents">
        <input type="checkbox" :id="subregion[0].subregion" > <label :for="subregion[0].subregion">{{ subregion[0].subregion }}</label>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="country of subregion">
              <input type="checkbox" :id="country.name" > <label :for="country.name">{{ country.name }} (+{{ country.callingCodes[0]}})</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Full code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kw1vmvqy/

How do I implement a method so when I check/uncheck a continent check box it checks/unchecks all the country check boxes in it? Also if I uncheck one country check box - it unchecks the appropriate continent check box.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is to bind values and v-models to your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="subregion[0].subregion" v-model="subregionCheck" :value="subregion[0].subregion">

<input type="checkbox" :id="country.name" v-model="countryCheck" :value="country.name">
```

And add arrays of subregionCheck and countryCheck in your data:

```
  data: {
    subregions: null,
    countries: null,
    query: '',
    countryList: [],
    subregionCheck:[],
    countryCheck: []
  },
```

These arrays serve as a markers for our checkboxes: if they contains the value of a single checkbox, it will be checked. At the start both of them are empty.

On the next step we should create a listener for subregion checkbox and a function to check all countries checkboxes for this subregion. Let's add a click listener first to our subregion:

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="subregion[0].subregion" v-model="subregionCheck" :value="subregion[0].subregion" @click="checkAllCountries(subregion)">
```

and then specify the method (as far as you're not using ES6, I need to delegate "this" to variable):

```
checkAllCountries: function (subregion) {
        var that = this;
        if (this.subregionCheck.indexOf(subregion[0].subregion) > -1) {
            subregion.forEach(function (element) {
              if (that.countryCheck.indexOf(element.name) <= -1) {
                that.countryCheck.push(element.name);
              }
            });
      }
      else {
         subregion.forEach(function (element) {
            that.countryCheck.splice(that.countryCheck.indexOf(element.name), 1);
        })
      }
    },
```

Now we need a method to uncheck subregion checkbox if one of its countries is unchecked. Add the click listener to countries checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="country.name" v-model="countryCheck" :value="country.name" @click="checkSubregion(subregion)">
```

and then specify the method:

```
checkSubregion: function (country) {
  if ((this.countryCheck.indexOf(country.name) <= -1) && this.subregionCheck.indexOf(country.subregion) > -1 ) {
    this.subregionCheck.splice(this.subregionCheck.indexOf(country.subregion), 1);
  }
},
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yo328o9s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is too bigger think to do here. Check [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/tws26tvx/) to get an idea. Here countries under subregion gets checked when a subregion gets checked. But not vice-versa and complete. You can follow that that way to create dynamic model binding. But it'll be a bit slow as you'll have to traverse stuffs a lot on each change.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(subregion, index) in continents">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="subregion[0].subregion" v-on:change="onSubregionChecked(subregion[0].subregion)">
    <label :for="subregion[0].subregion">{{ subregion[0].subregion }}</label>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="country in subregion">
        <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="onCountryChanged(country)" v-model="countryMap[country.alpha3Code].isChecked" :id="country.name">
        <label :for="country.name">{{ country.name }} (+{{ country.callingCodes[0]}})</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in script:

```
fetchData: function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var self = this;
  xhr.open('GET', apiURL);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    self.countryList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    _.each(self.countryList, function(country) {
      self.countryMap[country.alpha3Code] = {
        country: country.alpha3Code,
        isChecked: false,
        subRegion: country.subregion
      };
    });
  };
  xhr.send();
},
onSubregionChecked(val) {
  const self = this;
  self.countryMap = _.mapValues(self.countryMap, function(countryInSubRegion) {
    if (_.isObject(countryInSubRegion) && countryInSubRegion.subRegion === val) {
      countryInSubRegion.isChecked = true;
    }
    return countryInSubRegion;
  });
}
```

Again, this is not a working solution - it'll just give you a heads up to take your journey ahead.